# primeng p-cell editor input change function only works when clicking off, not when pressing enter

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, onchange

I have the following p-cellEditor code, however, if the (change) function only works if i click off the row. If i press enter on the keyboard instead, the (change) function is never triggered. Is there a way around this, so it triggers on both?

```
        <p-cellEditor>
          <ng-template pTemplate="input">
            <input
              (change)="validateRow(row)"
              pInputText
              class="p-inputtext"
              type="text"
              [(ngModel)]="row[column.field_name]"
            />
          </ng-container>
        </p-cellEditor>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `change` works on `blur`, if you want immediate events to fire on typing go for `input` instead, another way is to use `ngModelChange` combined with [`ngModelOptions`](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) with `updateOn` set to `change`.

> updateOn: Defines the event upon which the form control value and validity update. Defaults to 'change'. Possible values: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'.

html

```
<input (change)="test()" /> <br />
<input (input)="test()" /> <br />
<input
  [(ngModel)]="name"
  (ngModelChange)="test()"
  [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'change' }"
/>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  test() {
    console.log('changed');
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3qwfb)